# Application_BeginRequest event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I'm working with Application_BeginRequest event which is supposed to be triggered when request to some url is made.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == DummyPageUrl)
        {
            RegisterCacheEntry();
        }
    }
```

And here is the code I used to request url:

```
private void HitPage()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadData(DummyPageUrl);            
    }
```

But Application_BeginRequest event is not firing.
I have also tried this in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
```

which didn't work. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using classic or integrated pipeline for the IIS application pool?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in global.asax?

try this in Global.asax page....

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
```